# how can a chrome extension check if the website currently on has a specific javascript attached to it in the header

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I want to have my chrome extension check if the the dom contains a script called PDF.js.

I have tried :

```
document.head.getElementsByTagName("script").getAttribute("src")
```

and compared this with the address that I know the js script was assigned to by the html (in the header) here:

```
<header>
<base href="resource://pdf.js/web/">
<script src="../build/pdf.js"></script>
```

Is there an easier way to see if the website is using a specific js file?

Answer (score 0):

Always check the console. It's currently singing at you since

```
document.head.getElementsByTagName("script").getAttribute("src")
```

will error. `getElementsByTagName()` returns a [HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that you must iterate over before checking any individual script's `src` attribute.

Better would be to use a query selector like this:

```
if (document.querySelector('script[src$="PDF.js"]').length) {
    alert('has script');
}
```

`$` is inspired by REGEX syntax; it means the PDF.js part we're looking for must occur at the end of the `src` attribute, not merely somewhere in it.

Comment: Nitpick: no need for `.length` as it's a single DOM element. Also, `pdf.js` isn't necessarily at the end...

Comment: Good point re: `.length`. It'll falsy itself anyway if not found. Re: your other point, you mean in terms of there may be a query string?

Comment: 1) it'll be `null.length` which is a runtime error, 2) yeah.

Comment: I have tried var theScripts = document.querySelector("script[src$='pdf.js']"); It says its null unfortunatly :/

Comment: Yeah I have been thinking that aswell, but I am waiting to "run_at": "document_end" (in my manifest.json), so I thought that it has to be there by then(in the dom)?

Comment: Time for some debugging, then. Best would be to gether up all `script` tags via `querySelectorAll()` and see what you get back, whether it's there. That may show you that the selector isn't working, or that its filename isn't quite what you think it is, etc.